# Tensorflow DNNClassifier ValueError

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to write a fairly simple classifier using Tensorflow. The classifier will take in a 128 element vector and output a 2 category response.

Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas
import time

# Data sets
TRAINING = "james/data/tensorflow/matching/training.csv"
TEST = "james/data/tensorflow/matching/testing.csv"

# Load datasets.
training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(
    filename=TRAINING,
    target_dtype=np.int,
    features_dtype=np.float32
    )

test_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(
    filename=TEST,
    target_dtype=np.int,
    features_dtype=np.float32)

# Specify that all features have real-value data
feature_columns = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("", dimension=128)]

# Build 3 layer DNN with 10, 20, 10 units respectively.
classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                            hidden_units=[256,128,64, 32, 8],
                                            n_classes=2,
                                            )

print(training_set.target)
print(training_set.data)

# Fit model.
classifier.fit(x=training_set.data,
               y=training_set.target, 
               max_steps=10000
               )
```

The code is based entirely on the code found on the Tensorflow website.

I can see that both `training_set.data` and `training_set.target` are parsed correctly.

At the classifier stage I get an error:

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
ipython-input-9-aae84e4745a3 in module()
     35 classifier.fit(x=training_set.data,
     36                y=training_set.target,
---> 37                max_steps=10000
     38                )
     39
```

I also get an error at the bottom of the trace saying:

```
ValueError: Shapes (?, 1) and (?,) are incompatible
```

I am using an IPython Notebook to program in, with the latest TensorFlow library installed (last night's nightly build).

Comment: Can you post the complete error, including the stack traces? I don't have enough information to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the 1st line in your CSV file should be a header describing the batch of data in it for this function to work, like so:

```
n_samples, n_features, label_name_1, label_name_2, label_name_3
```

for example if you have a csv file with 100 examples, 5 features and only two labels, say "cat" and "dog", the first line of the csv should go something like this:

```
100, 5, cat, dog
```

that's it! (taken from [Error loading .csv into tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176989/error-loading-csv-into-tensorflow))

if that doesn't solve it, it could be related to this bug, which hasn't yet been addressed https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5284