# Error loading .csv into tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I've taken the prefabricated code that trains on the Iris csv and attempted to use my own csv.

The error is occurring here

```
train_data = "train_data.csv"
test_data = "test_data.csv"

training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(
filename=train_data,
target_dtype=np.int,
features_dtype=np.float32)
```

with the error

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'feature1'
```

the csv looks like this

```
feature1,feature2,feature3,label
1028.0,1012.0,1014.0,1
1029.0,1011.0,1017.0,-1
1027.0,1013.0,1015.0,1
...(and so on)
```

I get that the error is trying to say that feature1 is not an integer. However, when I use the same code for the Iris dataset, there are string headers that are not used as tensors. The Iris data csv looks like this.

```
30,4,setosa,versicolor,virginica
5.9,3.0,4.2,1.5,1
6.9,3.1,5.4,2.1,2
5.1,3.3,1.7,0.5,0
```

Also, not sure if I should make this a different question, but I changed the feature headers to

```
1,2,3,4
1028.0,1012.0,1014.0,1
1029.0,1011.0,1017.0,-1
1027.0,1013.0,1015.0,1
...(and so on)
```

and am now getting this error

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3) into shape (2)
```

Any ideas or help are greatly appreciated! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use this function, you have to write the dataset in the expected format. The first row should be like:

```
n_samples, n_features, [feature names]
```

For example, the one for the iris dataset you are showing has the correct format:

```
30,4,setosa,versicolor,virginica
```

i.e. 30 samples 4 features

If you have 50 samples in the dataset you created it should be like:

```
50,4,labelname
1028.0,1012.0,1014.0,1
1029.0,1011.0,1017.0,-1
1027.0,1013.0,1015.0,1
...(and so on)
```

Comment: my god I've looking everywhere for the explanation to that error "could not broadcast input array from shape x to x" and this was it! I was trying to use my own csv file without a header at all

Comment: thanks so much btw! this was really giving me a headache!